# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Disable AntiForgeryToken refresh on every page load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, antiforgerytoken

I wanted to Disable AntiForgeryToken refresh on every page load. Instead it show come up with unique `AntiForgeryToken` for every browser session. Like CSRF in PHP Laravel.

I am clueless if there is any option to disable it on every page load or enable it to throw unique token for every broswer session.

Reason is i am using it in one of my SPA application which ultimately never reloads any page because of angular and ajax requests and the problem is when i successfully submit the form once to the server then `AntiForgeryToken` Expires and gives error.

Comment: It shouldn't fail if you are doing form post, Are you posting json in your ajax?

Comment: yeah i am posting json to server

Comment: Take in mind that AntiForgeryToken doesn't work for Http Get requests because it relies on submitted cookies also called double Submit Cookies, see more in : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Double_Submit_Cookies

Comment: no i am doing post i haven't used get yet

Comment: You don't need the antiforgerytoken if you are requiring JSON for that POST action. The SOP will prevent the browser from sending `application/json` to other origin.

Comment: @vtortola, what does SOP stands for?

Comment: Same Origin Policy : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy